# Disconnect event not working in multiparty mode in the Amazon Connect using connect streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, transfer, amazon-connect

There are three parties: the customer, agent 1, and agent 2. They are in connected multiple-party mode.

We tried to fetch the call is disconnected on the transfer side , if the call is disconnected.
We have tried to get connection status, but the connection status is still connected on the agent side, though it ended on the other side

We are expecting a way to identify the transffered call is disconnected from their end, usuallywe didn't receive in ny events whethr the call is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your question. This is my understanding: You have a multiparty call with 2 agents and 1 customer. At some point, the customer gets disconnected, but the 2 agents are still connected. You want to get notified when the customer gets disconnected.

The answer: You'll have two contact records in this scenario. You'll need to listen to events on both, using Event Bridge. One of the contact records will end when the customer disconnects.

Comment: thank you for your concern ,I will check and update when it is working

Comment: hi i could not use the Event bridge , to trigger the ContactEventData to lambda or Cloud watch, but there is any way we can set amazon ccp as target to directly receive the event data in agent side